Using HTTP-response code 404 as a response to indicate that a resource was not found
I have recently had a discussion with some of my collegues about the 404 HTTP-response code. I have been using the response code as a way to indicate, that something was not found in one way or another. Usually with a response body detailing what was not found.
Let's say I have an API where someone can post an item in the request body that belongs to a number of collections. In this example there are multiple field that should have the id of that collection. This could be the id of business department, id of the original site the item was placed at, and the id of the destination for the item. If one of these ids does not match any rows in the table, I would respond with a 404 response code and a body that has the text: "No sites could be found with the id {id}".
Some of my colleagues disagereed with this approach and said that they believed that the 404 response should only be used if somthing in the route was wrong. Their reasoning being that if you send a request to the server where somthing in the route is wrong e.g. /usr/10/resetPassword instead of /user/10/resetPassword you would also get a 404 response. Their suggestion was to respond with 400 instead, and still keep the same body.
I under stand this reasoning, because with their approach you would always look at the route whenever you get a 404, but in my mind the request is not bad in the traditional sense and a 404 response seems more appropriate.

Are your IDs provided in HTTP path, in query parameters or in the request body? Because if the resource path by itself is valid, 404 may be a misleading response.

Your colleagues are wrong, and you got it right, but this is a common misconception. The HTTP standard itself has no concept of 'routes'. This is entirely an invention of of server-side frameworks. The only thing a generic HTTP client sees is a path that leads to some resource. How the code is structured that handles the request is from the perspective of the protocol an implementation detail.
If that resource doesn't exist, the correct status code is 404. (or sometimes 410 might be more appropriate). why that resource doesn't exist (your app doesn't match the url pattern to some controller, or it points to a database record that doesn't exist) is irrelevant to the generic HTTP client.
It may be helpful for a developer of your API to get some more information on what was wrong with the request though, because the difference between 'this record didn't exist' and 'I've built the URL incorrectly' could be helpful in debugging the client. The best place to put this sort of information is in a response body, perhaps using the application/problem+json type.
Also when in doubt, read the spec: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc9110#status.404

Hey, your answer makes sense, but one thing I can not grasp is why the 400 status code will be wrong to use in this context!

@KhaledHasan The 400 error is basically the catch-all client error, that's useful if there's not a more specific status code available for your specific use-case. Since there is a good appropriate code for this, it's better to use that specific one rather than the generic 'something went wrong' error.

@KhaledHasan I'll add that it's not the end of the world to use the generic code, it's just not the most correct.

Updated:
I agree with your colleagues.
It's no harm to use 404, but it may create ambiguity.
If you do not want to use the generic 400 bad request error, you can use the "422" error code (if you insist :)).
This comes in handy to tackle validation errors,
something like you mention above: "If one of these ids does not match any rows in the table, I would respond...")
422 indicates that the server understands the content type of the request entity and the syntax of the request entity is correct, but it was unable to process the contained instructions.
To get a better understanding, you can go over this MDN web document.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status#client_error_responses
I hope this helps

Note that 422 is specifically about the content of the request, which in HTTP parlance is about the request body

HTTP status codes are metadata of the transfer-of-documents-over-a-network domain.  They exist so that general purpose HTTP components (browsers, spiders, caches) can do useful work without knowing anything about the resources in question.
This is, in part, a expression of REST's uniform interface constraint: all resources on the web use the same self-descriptive messages.  A browser doesn't need to know if you are fetching representations from a file store, or a blog, or a book shop, or a gallery of kitten videos; the meanings of the messages are do not vary with the nature of the resource.
Further more, the "reason phrase" is not significant

The reason-phrase element exists for the sole purpose of providing a textual description associated with the numeric status code, mostly out of deference to earlier Internet application protocols that were more frequently used with interactive text clients -- RFC 9112; sec 4

So NOT FOUND is just a hint, not a definition; the actual meaning of 404 is closer to

The 404 (Not Found) status code indicates that the origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists. (RFC 9110 section 15.5.5)

Where the "target resource" is the thing identified in the request (see RFC 9110 section 7.1 if you want to get into the details).
The standard also says that 404 is heuristically cacheable, and because it is of the client error class of status codes therefore such a response does not automatically invalidate previously cached responses, and so on....

Now, let's not kid ourselves - if getting this wrong were catastrophic (think Ariadne), then there wouldn't be any debate at all because we would "all" understand the risks.
So at worst we are dealing with a small amount of friction being multiplied by web scale; in most common cases the lifetime cost of the mistake will be less than the expense of a meeting to discuss it....

But pretending it actually matters....
The key question is whether general purpose HTTP components will be significantly mislead by the implications of 404 compared to some other choice.
For example, a reasonable alternative to 404 would be 403 (the server understood the request but refuses to fulfill it).
Is there benefit to having general purpose components understand that your request is heuristically cacheable?  If there are, do those benefits outweigh the costs?

Based on what you describe here, I don't think you are going to be deriving a lot of benefit from trying to finesse different HTTP status codes to match the different branches of outcome in your bespoke processing.
'cuz that's not what status codes are for.
The fact that the server received an empty result set in response to some query during its internal processing is an implementation detail, and certainly not of interest to general purpose components.
To be honest, I wouldn't consider 400 either - it's equally (or perhaps even less) harmless than 404, but the text in the standard implies that there was a problem detected in the request, whereas in your case the request is understood to be well formed, but in conflict with information at the server.
If I ran the zoo, you would be expected to use a 403 Forbidden - you understood the request, you are declining to fulfill it, and that's what the general purpose components need to understand.  All the nuance you want to describe that is specific to your processing becomes part of the representation of the explanation of the error.
But as mistakes go, it's low risk - I doubt I'd sacrifice a deadline to wait for this to be "fixed"....
